# Connecting with Thunar through two layers of sftp

Tags: networking, ssh, sftp, thunar

Is it possible to make a graphical connection through 2 layers of ssh, using Thunar? For a single "layer" I can open the remove host by typing `sftp://user@host` in the address bar, and then work with files on `host` as if they were locally available.

Now, however, I am in a situation where my target `host2` is invisible from the www, so I have to ssh onto `host1`, and from there ssh again, to `host2`, within the local network. A "pseudocode" solution would look like `sftp://user1@host1/stfp://user2@host2/`, but this doesn't work.

The goal is to comfortably edit files on `host2`, using my locally installed GUI tools.

Comment: I have never used sshfs. Looking at a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) it seems that I would need root privileges on `host1` to do the mounting, which is unfortunately not the case. (I do however have them on `host2` if that changes anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Using `sshfs`. On host one you need to mount the remote directory to some directory:
   `sshfs user@host2:/directory /mountpoint` then on your computer you just have to open `sftp://user1@host1/mountpoint`. Sshfs uses [libfuse](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) to mount filesystem in userspace. It is not needed to have superuser permissions. It is mostly enough to be in `fuse` usergroup.
2. Port redirection - making it possible to "directly" connect via ssh from your computer to host2. Just execute a command: `ssh user1@host1 -L 2022:host2:22`
   then you can access host2 from your own computer by:
   `ssh user2@127.0.0.1 -p 2022`
   When you're using this method you have to instruct your thunar to use other port (in the example it is 2022). How to do this? You can find it here: [How do I connect to a server with thunar in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70423/how-do-i-connect-to-a-server-with-thunar-in-xubuntu) - `sftp://user2@127.0.0.1:2022/directory`

Comment: 1. The command `sshfs` isn't being found on `host1` and I am not sure if I can install it in my own "user space" (I am no unix hacker)


2. This works really nice, lacks just one thing: the GUI connection to Thunar. `ssh user2@127.0.0.1 -p 2022` in the address bar won't work. I imagine I could already use `-X` to run Xwindow and get _something_, but that's not ideal

Comment: If you have root privileges on host1 then install it from your distribution repository (`sudo apt-get install sshfs`).

Comment: That's the thing - I don't. Only on `host2`. And, moreover, this is some weird in-house distribution of my uni, it seems, so `apt-get` wouldn't work anyway

Comment: Then use second suggested method. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now it works. Dzięki!